# How to bypass Resque in a development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, development-environment, resque

Sometimes running too many servers locally while developing can get out of hand.

How would a Rails app that has [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) (which uses [Redis](http://redis.io/)), bypass the need for resque to be running, and just execute the perform method right away?

I want to be able to not have to run those two servers all the time when developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to the bottom of `config/environments/development.rb`

```
# bypass resque in the development environment
if Rails.env.development?
    module Resque
        def self.enqueue(klass, *args)
            klass.perform(*args)
        end
    end
end
```